# AngularJS Client Consume Magneto Server? Via Rest or SOAP?

Tags: php, angularjs, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Hi I am building an application based on Magento CE 1.9.2

I have previous experience with magento but not recently or experience using the API, either SOAP or REST.

I am trying to decide whether or not it is fully beneficial or it is recommended to to abstract the client allow a fully fledged e-commerce store using an angular client / magento.

I am trying to see if it efficient to integrate AngularJs within Magento or have an Angular client making calls to the Magento API.

I have found this resource and i am investigating:
https://github.com/Wildhoney/Magento-on-Angular

This seems like an interested libary but before i start i wanted to see what the limitations where for accessing data through either SOAP or REST.

Specially as i am building this application for a  client who requires the basic shoping aspects and noting to advanced, is there any data / functionality which magento would not be able to send to the client to utilise?

I wish to have the angular client ( this can be on a PHP based app such as laravel like in Magento-on-angular), i need to be able to get all the products, post reviews and interact with say magento modules, modules which work with say instragram and pull down the review pictures which will be sent to a client, i wish to make a full angular checkout and simply post a checkout object (something alone those lines) to magento for it to parse.

my objective is to have a minimal client which does not lack in functionality and i am very proficient in angular, angular was chosen due to the front end requirements of the application.

Or any other constraints or advice?

Or a Pro's / Con's List.

Thanks